# python socket server wait multi clients complete sending message

Tags: python, sockets

there are two types of client which will send messages to socket server.

```
for i in range(n):
 client.send('1')
client.send('complete')
client.close()



for i in range(n):
 client.connect(server)
 client.send('2')
 client.close()
client.connect(server)
client.send('complete')
client.close()
```

As a server how to listen 2 types client the same time ?  The server need wait all client 'complete' then do someting.

I have tried to make `server.linsten(1)` then start multi thread. if the server receive 'complete' then close thread. server will wait till thread count is 1 then do someting.

```
def continuous_receive():
        try:
            sock, addr = server.accept()
            while 1:
                data=sock.recv(1024).decode('utf8')
                if not data:
                    sock.close()
                    sock, addr = server.accept()
                else:
                    print(addr[0]+' '+data)
                if data=='complete':
                    break
        except:
            print('wait client time out')

for i in range(client_count):
        t=threading.Thread(target=continuous_receive)
        t.start()
```

But it doesn't work well. the '2' client will crowd into the same thread and another thread will  timeout.

Is there any other way can handle this?

Comment: The built-in [`socketserver.ThreadingMixIn`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/socketserver.html#module-socketserver) class will spawn a thread per client; you could do the same.

Comment: Another concern: `sock.recv(1024)` will likely not be enough for actual work with a TCP stream; you'll need a framing scheme of some sort, be it e.g. just waiting until a newline or a TLV scheme or whatnot.

Comment: @AKX if there are olny '2' client now, which send message will close connection and start a new connection.   maybe there's a moment the total thread count is 1, but the client is not 'complete'.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. Could you maybe elaborate what your actual system will be here? Broadcasting messages from an `1` client to connected `2` clients?

Comment: @AKX '1' client is always connected with server, '2' client will disconnect some times with server when running. the server need to wait both client 'complete' then do something. because the running time of 2 kinds client is not the same, maybe '1' is 'complete' but '2' is still running. which will cause the thread count is 1 when '2' is  not 'complete' but disconnected. I don't know if I'm describing it properly, sorry for my poor english.

Comment: How would the server know which client connection is of type 1, and which is of type 2? Your example code does not correlate the clients in the loop sending `complete` to their types.

Comment: @AKX server don't know which type client connected, but server know how many clients will connect with it. So i create the same number of child threads to wait client send 'complete', then end thread. when the current thread count is 1, it means all client have send 'complete'. But the question is the '2' client connection requests will crowd into the same thread and the count of thread and client will not be equal.

Comment: But if a single `2` client may connect multiple times (as I understand from "client will disconnect some times") you can't tell how many distinct clients have connected.

Comment: @AKX yes, you can see my code, there will be a `server.accept()` if a client disconnect but not complete. this make sure the thread is alive untill it receive a 'complete'. if `server.accept()` only accept 1 client in 1 thread, that's perfect. but the result is all client may crowd in 1 thread and the other thread occur timeout, even if i have setted `server.linsten(1)`

Comment: Yeah, so that's not how `accept()` works – it will accept any connection, not the "same" connection; the `1` in `listen(1)` means the socket's backlog of connections will be 1 long.

Comment: @AKX it doesn't matter which client connect if 1 thread only accept 1 client, but it seems  not work like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `select` is a better solution,because there is a single thread can monitor the `complete` count and break loop. code like:

```
server=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((ip, port))
server.listen(5)
inputs=[self.server]
outputs=[]
        complete=0
        while 1:
                # 10 means block 10s/cycle
                readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(inputs, outputs, inputs,10)
                for s in readable:
                    if s is self.server:
                        sock,addr=s.accept()
                        inputs.append(sock)
                    else:
                        data=s.recv(1024).decode('utf8')
                        if data:
                            logging.info('%s %s'%(s.getpeername(),data))
                        else:
                            logging.info('%s disconnect'%(s.getpeername()[0]))
                            inputs.remove(s)
                        if data=='complete':
                            inputs.remove(s)
                            complete+=1
                if complete==n:
                    self.server.close()
                    break
```

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
import socket
import select

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(('localhost', 8888))
server.listen(5)

clients_type_1 = []
clients_type_2 = []

def handle_type_1_client(client_socket):
    while True:
        data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        if not data:
            break
        if data == 'complete':
            clients_type_1.remove(client_socket)
            break

def handle_type_2_client(client_socket):
    while True:
        data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        if not data:
            break
        if data == 'complete':
            clients_type_2.remove(client_socket)
            break

while True:
    readable, _, _ = select.select([server] + clients_type_1 + clients_type_2, [], [])

    for sock in readable:
        if sock is server:
            client, addr = server.accept()
            data = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            if data == '1':
                clients_type_1.append(client)
                handle_type_1_client(client)
            elif data == '2':
                clients_type_2.append(client)
                handle_type_2_client(client)
        else:
            data = sock.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            if data == 'complete':
                sock.close()

server.close()
```

Comment: You should explain what's happening here – `select` is pretty intricate, and in any case, this will still block until a single client connection is done with.